# Can I create an Alexa skill that transmits a video to a TV through an echo dot

Tags: python, alexa-voice-service

I am currently working on an Alexa skill to be able to play a specific YouTube video through a voice command using an echo dot charcoal, I can do everything but I have the problem of sending the video to a TV that I have.

I can do this but only with an echo dot that has a screen, I could send it to a TV or someone will have experience doing it since I have not been able to or do not know how to do it

Comment: Do you have a skill ID that we test this on Echo show device ? I also wanted to clarify on steps involved in reproducing this on echo show and TV if possible so that I can better understand the concern
Since this appears to work properly on your echo show device and I assume you are using same Alexa account on TV are you not able to launch skill directly to play youtube video on TV ? Happy to help test this and assist if possible